# Why slot is appending multiple times despite following correct implementation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs-slots

Hi i'm using https://github.com/xwpongithub/vue-range-slider  plugin with `piecewise` slot

whatever content is there inside `piecewise` slot it is appending multiple times

as shown below in the image

https://ibb.co/kcX2rpC

here is my code

```js
new Vue({
  data() {
    return {
      value: [0,100]
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.min = 0
    this.max = 250
    this.enableCross = false
  },
  methods:{
     sliding(steps){
       console.log('steps',steps);
    }
  },
}).$mount('#app')
```

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

:root{
   --slider-color:#2196f3;
}

.app-content {
  padding:40px 15px;
}

.slider{
    height:150px !important;
}

.slider-always{
  width: 5px !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  cursor: w-resize !important;
  left: 5px !important;
  background: #2196f3 !important;
  top:0 !important;
}

.slider-process{
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    background-color: #ffffff !important;
}

.slider-process:before,.slider-process:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5px;
    background: var(--slider-color);
}
.slider-process:before{top:0}
.slider-process:after{bottom:0}

.slider-dot{border-radius:0 !important; box-shadow:none !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vue-range-component@1.0.2/dist/vue-range-slider.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-range-component@1.0.2/dist/vue-range-slider.min.js"></script>


<div id="app">
  <div class="app-content">
    <vue-range-slider v-model="value" :min="min" :max="max" :step="0.1" :enable-cross="enableCross" @slide-end="sliding($event)" :piecewise="true">
    
      <div class="diy-tooltip" slot="piecewise" >
          
         <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"/><p>Argentina</p></li>
        <li><img src="http://placehold.it/60x60"/><p>Brazil</p></li>
        
      </div>
      
    </vue-range-slider>
  </div>
</div>
```